# I want to refresh a table list only when I receive push notification in swiftUI

Tags: ios, listview, swiftui

I want to refresh my list using function call when I receive push notification. Earlier when I used `ObservedObject` list updating continuously and it looks like appear and disappear the list view continuously, now I am using `StateObject`, here list is refreshing only 1 time. I am very new in SwiftUI. Please suggest me how to refresh the else part each time when getting notification.

MapviewUI:

```
@StateObject var viewModel = SettingsViewModel()
@StateObject var vm = MapViewModel()
if pushNotificationReceived == false {
    ForEach(viewModel.users) { users in
        NavigationLink(destination: ChatSwiftUIView(chatUser: users)) {
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Text(users.email)
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
            }
        }
        .padding(.horizontal)
        .padding(.top, 8)
    }
}
else {
    ForEach(vm.users) { users in
        NavigationLink(destination: ChatSwiftUIView(chatUser: users)) {
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Text(users.email)
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
            }
        }
                  
        .padding(.horizontal)
        .padding(.top, 8)
    }
}
```

MapviewModel:

```
class MapViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var users = [ChatUsers]()
    func fetchAllUsers() {
        FirebaseManager.shared.fireStore.collection("users")
            .getDocuments { documentSnapshot, error in
                if let error = error {
                    print("Failed to fetch users : ", error)
                    return
                }

                documentSnapshot?.documents.forEach { snapshot in
                    let data = snapshot.data()
                    self.users.append(.init(data: data))
                }
            }
    }
}
```

SettingsViewModel:

```
@Published var users = [ChatUsers]()
func fetchAllUsers() {
    FirebaseManager.shared.fireStore.collection("users")
        .getDocuments { documentsSnapshot, error in
            if let error = error {
                print("Failed to fetch users: \(error)")
                return
            }

            documentsSnapshot?.documents.forEach { snapshot in
                let data = snapshot.data()
                let user = ChatUsers(data: data)
                if user.uid != FirebaseManager.shared.auth.currentUser?.uid {
                    self.users.append(.init(data: data))
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: This needs a [mre]. No one can run this code and there are important missing parts that relate directly to the question

Comment: Please take a [tour] and read [ask] for tips how to write a good question.

Comment: Only use ObserviableObject when another view or object creates the model and passes it in to your view. Since your view creates it, it should be StateObject. Your pattern in your view is a bit odd. If you only want it to update after a push, then consider creating a second users array in your view model and only update it when the push notification arrives. Then you can avoid the if/else in your view.